# Hexdigest() prompts bytes-like object is required, not 'str' Python Error

Tags: python, api, hash, python-requests, hmac

I'm trying to create and API request with the following code:

```
from hashlib import sha1
import base64, hmac, time, requests, json

account = 'some_instagram_account'
api_key = 'my_api_key'
api_secret = 'my_api_secret'

epoch_time = str(int(time.time()))

hashed = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(bytes(api_secret,'utf-8'), bytes(api_key + epoch_time,'utf-8'), sha1).hexdigest())
headers = {'X-Auth': hashed,'X-Time': str(int(time.time())),'X-Key': api_key}
url = 'https://api.fakecheck.co/instagram/'+account

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(json.loads(response.text))
```

But when using hexdigest() method I always get:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Can someone help me? This is the first time I´m making a request with a hashed key.

Comment: `.hexdigest().encode()`

Comment: You can also replace `bytes(api_secret,'utf-8')` with `api_secret.encode()` and `bytes(api_key + epoch_time,'utf-8')` with `(api_key + epoch_time).encode()`. Check [`str.encode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) docs, `utf-8` is default encoding.

Comment: Also `str(int(time.time()))` could be replaced with `f"{time.time():.0f}"` but that's just minor edit, you can skip it.